# SKTileMapNode Collisions not working

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to make a sidescroller using SKTileMapNode and SKTileMaps, but I'm having trouble with the physics bodies of individual tiles. I create them in a loop as described in this link:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/50043

However my player node passes through the ground. What am I doing wrong?

```
        guard let landBackground = childNode(withName: "ground")
        as? SKTileMapNode else {
            fatalError("Background node not loaded")
    }
    self.landBackground = landBackground
    self.tileSize = landBackground.tileSize

    for x in 0...(landBackground.numberOfColumns-1){
        for y in 0...(landBackground.numberOfRows-1){

            let tile = landBackground.tileDefinition(atColumn: x, row: y)
            if(tile != nil){
                let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tileSize.width, height: tileSize.height)
                let tileNode = SKShapeNode(rect: rect)

                tileNode.position = self.landBackground.centerOfTile(atColumn: x, row: y)

                tileNode.position.x -= (tileSize.width * 0.5)
                tileNode.position.y -= (tileSize.height * 0.5)

                tileNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: tileSize, center: tileNode.position)
                tileNode.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
                tileNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = playerCategory|groundCategory

                //tileNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = playerCategory
                tileNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = groundCategory
                landBackground.addChild(tileNode)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: tileSize, center: tileNode.position)`

This is probably not correct. The documentation for the call says:

> The center of the square in the owning node’s coordinate system.

This means you should probably use `.zero`. The physics body is always assumed to be at the same location as the node it belongs to, unless specifically offset. You should never use scene coordinates for this.

Also make sure you have `showsPhysics` set to `true` on your `SKView` so you can see where they really are.